# CSS/HTML how not to overlap fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have a twitter/facebook like header, a fixed one and a main content. When I would scroll down to my last line, the content div is overlapping the header. How can I avoid this?

this is the screenshot of my page:
[image]

**This is the structure of my html:**

```
<body>

<div>
<?php include("initcontrols/header.php"); echo $plHeader;?>   
</div>


<div id="mainform">
<noscript>It seems your browser doesn't support Javascript.<br /></noscript>

<!-- Apply blue theme as default for all tiles -->
<div id="tiles" class="blue">
<!-- Sliding Tile that shows 100% of the back tile every 3 seconds -->
<div class="live-tile" data-stops="100%" data-speed="750" data-delay="3000">
    <span class="tile-title">slide tile (figure 2a)</span>
    <div><img src="images/say.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="1" /></div>
    <div><img src="images/sayako.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="2" /></div>
</div>

    <!-- Red Flip Tile that flips every 4 seconds -->
<div class="red live-tile" data-mode="flip" data-delay="4000">
    <div>
        <img src="images/home.png" alt="3" />
        <a class="tile-title">flip tile front (figure 2b)</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="images/message.png" alt="4" />
        <a class="tile-title">flip tile back (figure 2b)</a>
        </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
// apply regular slide universally unless .exclude class is applied 
// NOTE: The default options for each liveTile are being pulled from the 'data-' attributes
$(".live-tile, .flip-list").not(".exclude").liveTile();
</script>

</div>
```

**My css:**

```
div#header{
padding-left:15px;
overflow:hidden;
position: fixed;
margin:0px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
background:#333333;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #736F6E, #111111) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
div#header-title{
color: #FFF;
float: left;
display:inline-block;
}
div#header h2{
margin: 0 0 0 3px;
z-index:12;
}
div#header h1{
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}

#mainform{
width:960px;
background: #F0F0F0;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
height: 2000px;
margin: 100px auto;

}
```

and for my live-tile look:
http://pastebin.com/cpBXYVRu
I used a template by http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs#applicationBar:

Comment: Have a read of this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index

Comment: Try setting up a JS Fiddle. It'll help a lot.

Comment: Does it have PHP? @MichaelGiovanniPumo

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes you know...I'm not sure, but in any case, you could just copy and paste the HTML from View->Source in your browser to the fiddle. With your PHP include above, we have no way of knowing what's in it.

Comment: try this buddy: http://jsfiddle.net/bettybarnes/WYdH6/

Comment: Is it just me or I don't see any div with the ID header in your HTML?

Comment: @KerrM because I used php: <div>
 <?php include("initcontrols/header.php"); echo $plHeader;?>   
</div>

Comment: in my header.php there is div id="header"

Comment: Okay - navigate to the php file in your browser, click on view->source, and update your HTML with the relevant parts there, so we may have a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the z-index of an element to position it behind another. In this instance, you would want to increase the z-index of your fixed header. Read more about z-index [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index).

Comment: I adjusted my z-index but my image button is still overlapping the header?

Comment: What image button? The red tile?

Comment: The div with the "live-tile" has a z-index of 30 as seen: `.live-tile .tile-title, .list-tile .tile-title { position:absolute; bottom:0px; font-size:12px; left:0px; width:100%; padding:0 0 6px 6px; z-index:30; }`, did you make sure your header div has a higher z-index?

Comment: thanks! I got it now! I increased my z-index in #header, I was wondering why it was not working, coz I added px.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is image there which makes your content to hide behind header you can clearly see like letter image and its position is absolute find it and check its z-index and give your content z-index less then it so that it remains behind that

Comment: Adjusting the z-index was already proposed in the answer by @KerrM. Moreover, the question is already 2 years old...